# How can I get all play counts for certain podcast?

Tags: soundcloud

I have a podcast which I am accessing by RSS to embed it in our web site. But I need to display the play count of all episodes. I can find the play count in the admin panel, but not in the RSS.

On the other hand, in the API documentation, there's a `play_count` field for a track. I guess if I loop through all tracks and fetch `play_count`, then I will receive the overall play count, right?

If that's true, I would like to ask the team to let me create an application, because it seems that's the only way to receive a `secret` and access the API.

Thank you